# linker error for FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to share some text and image on Facebook. For that I am using `FBSDKShareDialog`, but it's giving following linker error. I am using 4.5.1 version of facebook sdk.

```
 FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]]){
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
    }
    else {
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser; //or FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic
    }
    //dialog.shareContent = content;
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    [dialog show];
```

error is :

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKShareDialog", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SearchVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you drag FBSDKShareKit.framwork into your project.

[image: Include the binary]

Then link your binary to it.

[image]
[image]